# Dynamic custom SQL in Tableau

Tags: sql, dynamic, tableau-api

I'm using Tableau 9.0 to connect to an Amazon Redshift database. The data is such a high volume that only the last 4 months is stored. Each month, a new table is created, named with the current month, and the table from 5 months ago is dropped.

So what we have right now is 4 tables:

- events_jun
- events_jul
- events_aug
- events_sep

The custom SQL that I want to define will use the UNION ALL function to merge all 4 tables together into a single query. The issue is that the table names will need to be changed month over month.

Is there a way to define variables based on CURDATE, such that you can take CURDATE() - 90 and extract the first 3 letters, then append it to the string "events_" in order to create a concatenated string that is the table name you want.

Please note, I have tried to resolve the problem by including a parameter in the custom SQL, as described here: http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/mac/en-us/customsql.html

This does not work, because Tableau will surround the Paramter value with single quotes, which results in events_'jun' which of course throws an error, because there is not such table.

Comment: I don't know a lot about redshift but doing that with your data is  classic requirement for partitioning. Do you have a performance or size issue with putting data into multiple tables? Why don't you rename then events_0, events_1, events_2 and shuffle the data back instead?

Comment: The Tableau documentation that you link to states "Parameters can only replace literal values. They cannot replace expressions or identifiers such as table names.". So parameters are not your answer. I'd see if Redshift can define a view, or try the approaches @Nick.McDermid suggests above.